# I see and I hear

Tags: progressive-aspect, stative-verbs

Traditional English prescriptive grammar teaches that these two verbs, *to see* and *to hear*, when describing their sensory nature, should never be used in the progressive aspect of tenses.

Thus

> I am seeing you/I was seeing
>   I am hearing you/I was hearing you

would be incorrect.

But in spoken English, whether it be in the movies or on television, this usage seems to me to become ever more often used.

*I am seeing you* for *I see you now*

*I am hearing you* for *I hear you now*

When did this usage become so universally accepted? Is it still considered colloquial English? Or is it already considered standard English?

Comment: Please post where it is written that "I am seeing/hearing you" is incorrect

Comment: I suppose this is about stative verbs, which I am adding as a tag.

Comment: There's certainly nothing wrong with *hearing* being used to describe a "sensory experience": "No, can't hear you... No... Ah yes, I'm hearing you loud and clear."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While present progressive is routinely used to indicate an ongoing activity, it als can express an *evolving* activity. The clause *I am seeing you* is often used to indicate a dawning recognition

> *For the first time, I am seeing you for the cad that you are!*

Perception is often a report of a fairly momentary event, and in those cases, progressive would not necessarily need the progressive, even if the activity being observed is continuing.

> *Standing at the intersection, I [now] see numerous cars going through red lights.*

However, there are times when the observation is truly ongoing

> *We are seeing more and more politicians caught up in scandals.*

Similarly, these two sentences convey very similar concepts

> *I hear you!*
>
> *I am hearing you!*

However, the second sentence would be more likely to be used to convey a regular attentiveness in response to an ongoing demand rather than a request for a single moment of focus.

Comment: It's not that stative perception verbs are not usable in the progressive; it's that using them that way invites an interpretation that makes the sense impression ongoing. I.e, _*I'm seeing a bolt of lightning_ is odd, because it's instantaneous, but _I'm seeing bolts of lightning_ is perfectly fine. The progressive adds an interpretive clue, and the precise meaning is determined by the rest of the sentence, in context. After all, a lot of common English verbs have identical stative,  inchoative, and causative forms.

Comment: @PatrickCălinescu No. Because you are seeing numerous sequential bolts, it is an ongoing series of instantaneous events.